# Scrollview in Vertical View Pager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to create a vertical viewpager with scrollview in one of its fragment. The problem is when i am swiping up, i am not going into second fragment. I have uploaded my code in Github(`https://github.com/RajuMandala/verticalviewpager`). Please let me know, if i am doing anything wrong. Thanks for your time.

My FirstFragment.java code is below,

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    // Scrolling code
    private LinearLayout verticalOuterLayout;
    private ScrollView verticalScrollview;
    private TextView verticalTextView;
    private int verticalScrollMax;
    private Timer scrollTimer       =   null;
    private TimerTask clickSchedule;
    private TimerTask scrollerSchedule;
    private TimerTask faceAnimationSchedule;
    private int scrollPos = 0;
    private Boolean isFaceDown      =   true;
    private Timer clickTimer        =   null;
    private Timer faceTimer         =   null;
    private Button clickedButton    =   null;
    private String[] nameArray = {"Apple", "Banana", "Grapes", "Orange", "Strawberry","Apple", "Banana","Grapes"};
    private String[] imageNameArray = {"apple", "banana", "grapes", "orange", "strawberry","apple", "banana","grapes"};
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_frag,container,false);

        // Scrolling code
        verticalScrollview  =   (ScrollView) v.findViewById(R.id.vertical_scrollview_id);
        verticalOuterLayout =   (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.vertical_outer_layout_id);

        //addImagesToView();
        addTextsToView();

        ViewTreeObserver vto        =   verticalOuterLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
        /*vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                verticalOuterLayout.getViewTreeObserver().re
                getScrollMaxAmount();
                startAutoScrolling();
            }
        });*/
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                //
                // mycode
                //
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<16) {
                    removeLayoutListenerPre16(verticalOuterLayout.getViewTreeObserver(),this);
                } else {
                    removeLayoutListenerPost16(verticalOuterLayout.getViewTreeObserver(), this);
                }
                getScrollMaxAmount();
                startAutoScrolling();
            }
        });
        verticalOuterLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                return true;
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void removeLayoutListenerPre16(ViewTreeObserver observer, ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener listener){
        observer.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(listener);
    }

    @TargetApi(16)
    private void removeLayoutListenerPost16(ViewTreeObserver observer, ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener listener){
        observer.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);
    }


    // Scrolling code
    public void addTextsToView(){
        for (int i=0;i<nameArray.length;i++){
            final TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
            textView.setText(nameArray[i]);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params    =   new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(256,256);
            textView.setLayoutParams(params);
            verticalOuterLayout.addView(textView);
        }
    }

    public void getScrollMaxAmount(){
        int actualWidth = (verticalOuterLayout.getMeasuredHeight()-(256*3));
        verticalScrollMax   = actualWidth;
    }

    public void startAutoScrolling(){
        if (scrollTimer == null) {
            scrollTimer                 =   new Timer();
            final Runnable Timer_Tick   =   new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    moveScrollView();
                }
            };

            if(scrollerSchedule != null){
                scrollerSchedule.cancel();
                scrollerSchedule = null;
            }
            scrollerSchedule = new TimerTask(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);
                }
            };

            scrollTimer.schedule(scrollerSchedule, 30, 30);
        }
    }

    public void moveScrollView(){
        scrollPos                           =   (int) (verticalScrollview.getScrollY() + 1.0);
        if(scrollPos >= verticalScrollMax){
            scrollPos                       =   0;
        }
        verticalScrollview.scrollTo(0,scrollPos);
    }

    public void onDestroy(){
        clearTimerTaks(clickSchedule);
        clearTimerTaks(scrollerSchedule);
        clearTimerTaks(faceAnimationSchedule);
        clearTimers(scrollTimer);
        clearTimers(clickTimer);
        clearTimers(faceTimer);

        clickSchedule         = null;
        scrollerSchedule      = null;
        faceAnimationSchedule = null;
        scrollTimer           = null;
        clickTimer            = null;
        faceTimer             = null;

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void clearTimers(Timer timer){
        if(timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer = null;
        }
    }

    private void clearTimerTaks(TimerTask timerTask){
        if(timerTask != null) {
            timerTask.cancel();
            timerTask = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Please see the screenshot of first fragment below,
[image]

Comment: It is really hard to go through all your code to identify what the problem is. Typically, you should identify what the problem is specifically (i.e. why is it not scrolling) and we might be able to point you in the right direction for a fix. As of this particular problem, it is not a good idea to nest scrollable components within each other.

Comment: @Emmanuel Thank you for the quick response. The auto scroll is working fine. But when i am swiping up the second fragment is not loading up. If u can setup the code from Gihub, it will be a great help for me.